# Magento 2 - Cron groups explaination

Tags: magento2.2, magento-cron

What is the purpose of below configuration in cron group xml file? I did not fully understand the meaning of those lines:

**schedule_generate_every**

Frequency (in minutes) that schedules are written to the cron_schedule table.

**schedule_ahead_for**

Time (in minutes) in advance that schedules are written to the cron_schedule table.

**schedule_lifetime**

Window of time (in minutes) that cron job must start or will be considered missed (“too late” to run).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`schedule_generate_every`: How often would you like your job to run? Every minute, every 5 minutes, every hour, every day...

`schedule_ahead_for`: How far in advance would you like to schedule jobs? Example: cron runs at 1pm. schedule_ahead_for is set to 1 hour. Cron jobs for the next hour are scheduled.

`schedule_lifetime`: In the event that the job's scheduled time passes without the job running, should Magento skip the job? If the schedule_lifetime is zero, yes, Magento skips it. If this value is 5 minutes and the job is expired by only 4 minutes, then Magento will run the job.

Comment: For more info: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/cron.html