# Magento 2 - How to run a script asynchronously?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

In Magento 2, I trigger `catalog_product_save_before` event.

But this observer takes a lot of time to run and it result with a 504 error.

So i would like to know if it is possible and how to run an observer asynchronously even if the event is "save_before" ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

While it would be technically possible to dispatch events asynchronously it would break pretty much everything as a single request can trigger 100's/1000's of observers changing how the entire application behaves.

If anything I would recommend identifying what is causing the timeout using a profiler. Take a look at things like, Xdebug profiler, Xhprof, Blackfire, NewRelic, all different types but should help identify the cause.

Alternatively for a simple approach if you have Xdebug working place a breakpoint on line 1 of each of the `execute()` methods that observe the `catalog_product_save_before` event and step over each line until until you find the culprit.

If you mean you have created a custom observer and it takes a long time to run then I would suggest instead of executing your logic in the observer class directly you instead add a message to the Magento message-queue, and then you do your time-consuming logic within the queue consumer itself.

Note: Do not run Xdebug on your production environment as it will make everything slow to a crawl in comparison to normal.

Answer (score 0):

A work around to your issue is to add a cron and for every product that has been updated in the last 5mins (this can vary of course), you would perform your process in the background.

You would pull the products for which the field `updated_at` in the table `catalog_product_entity` match your constraint and then the code would be the same as what you have today.

Do be careful when crons are long to run, they can break your queuing system.

--> you may want to look at assigning your cron in a group of its one
see: [Magento 2 - Cron groups explaination](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215467/magento-2-cron-groups-explaination)

--> else, it may wise to watch the process and possibly externalise it as a command-line if required.